# SQLite SUM function and strings

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following problem.

Let's say that I have a table `foo`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    mycolumn INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ("");
```

then, the result of `SELECT SUM(mycolumn) FROM foo;` is:

```
SUM(mycolumn)
-------------
3.0
```

If I updated the empty string to `NULL` the result would be `3`. It is understandable as aggregate functions disregard `NULL` values. However, I do not understand the floating point result given above (3.0).

I cannot find any information about TEXT to REAL conversion on [SQLite Datatypes page](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Therefore, I have the following question:

**Is there an automatic conversion from TEXT to REAL storage class when an aggregate function is used?**

PS. I am using version 3.34.1 of SQLite.

Comment: Hi @hanshenrik it refers to the  result given above: 3.0

Comment: I checked the documentation, and `SUM` may actually return an integer: `The result of sum() is an integer value if all non-NULL inputs are integers. If any input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a floating point value which might be an approximation to the true sum.` The result in my question is a floating point number because string is not a `NULL` or an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the SQLite documentation on aggregates](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc):

> The result of sum() is an integer value if all non-NULL inputs are integers. If any input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a floating point value which might be an approximation to the true sum.

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

[Check the sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc)

> sum(X) total(X)
>
> The sum() and total() aggregate functions return sum of all non-NULL
> values in the group. If there are no non-NULL input rows then sum()
> returns NULL but total() returns 0.0. NULL is not normally a helpful
> result for the sum of no rows but the SQL standard requires it and
> most other SQL database engines implement sum() that way so SQLite
> does it in the same way in order to be compatible. The non-standard
> total() function is provided as a convenient way to work around this
> design problem in the SQL language.
>
> The result of total() is always a floating point value. The result of
> sum() is an integer value if all non-NULL inputs are integers. If any
> input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a
> floating point value which might be an approximation to the true sum.
>
> Sum() will throw an "integer overflow" exception if all inputs are
> integers or NULL and an integer overflow occurs at any point during
> the computation. Total() never throws an integer overflow.